# Selecting limited results from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select

I apologise if this has been asked before. I'm still not certain how to phrase my question for the title, so wasn't sure what to search for.

I have a hundred or so databases in the same instance, one for each of my customers, named for the customer, and they all have the same structure. I want to select a single result set that includes the database name along with the most recent date entry in one of the tables. I can pull the database names from sys.databases, but then for each database I want to select the most recent date from Events.Date_Logged so that my result set looks something like this:

```
 _______________________________
|               |               |
|Cust_Name      |Latest_Event   |
|_______________|_______________|
|               |               |
|Customer1      |01/02/2020     |
|_______________|_______________|
|               |               |
|Customer2      |02/02/2020     |
|_______________|_______________|
|               |               |
|Customer3      |03/02/2020     |
|_______________|_______________|
```

I'm really struggling with the syntax though. I either get just a single row returned or every single event for each customer. I think my joins are as rusty as hell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not being sure is no reason not to try. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Comment: Please show what you tried. Please don't ask us to write code for you. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) [ask] For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest you do:

1. Declare a result variable (of type table)
2. Use a cursor to go over every database
3. Inside the cursor: do a select top 1 ... order by date desc to get the most recent record. Save this result in the result variable.
4. After the cursor print the result variable.

That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, Melisa. Wouldn't that create a separate result set for each iteration of the loop i.e. for each database? I need all of the results in a single result set.

Comment: If you create the table variable before the cursor and insert all the results in that variable -> after the cursor there will be 1 variable with all the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will give that a try.